# append 2 worksheet to 3th worksheet excel vba

Tags: excel, append, vba

I first want to copy all rows from sheet evaluatierooster_NL to sheet evaluatierooster_NLFR. Then I want to append all rows (except first row) from sheet evaluatierooster_FR to sheet evaluatierooster_NLFR. I get an error on the line below that object is missing?

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=evaluatierooster_NLFR.Range("A1"), _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'~~> Copy evaluatierooster_NL to evaluatierooster_NLFR
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NL").Select
Rows("1:" & Rows.Count).Copy
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("evaluatierooster_FR").Select
Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Copy
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Select

Dim LastRow As Long

Set LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=evaluatierooster_NLFR.Range("A1"), _
                                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Paste
```

Comment: you get an error because you have defined **LastRow as Long** so you don't need to use the *Set* keyword which is only for variable references that return an object.

I have provided an alternative code below, but you could just remove the **Set**

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
'~~> Copy evaluatierooster_NL to evaluatierooster_NLFR
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("evaluatierooster_NL").Select
Rows("1:" & Rows.Count).Copy
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("evaluatierooster_FR").Select
Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Copy
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Select

' get the last row (same as doing CTRL+Up keystroke in Excel)    
LastRow = activesheet.range("A65536").end(xlup).row+1

ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Paste
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("evaluatierooster_NL").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("evaluatierooster_NL").Rows("1:" & lastRow).Copy Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Range("A1")

 lastRow = Sheets("evaluatierooster_FR").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
 Sheets("evaluatierooster_FR").Rows("2:" & lastRow).Copy Sheets("evaluatierooster_NLFR").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```